# Scala invoke Object apply method using string

Tags: scala, object, reflection, polymorphism, scala-reflect

I have a class **MyFilter** which has many different versions. Depending on the input version, I want to invoke that object and apply that filter. Sample is shown below:

```
object v1{
  def apply(l: List[String]) = {
    l.filter(_.contains("v1"))
  }
}

object v2{
  def apply(l: List[String]) = {
    l.filter(_.contains("v2"))
  }
}

object MyFilter {
  
  def apply(version: String) = (l: List[String]) => {
    println("Applying Filter")
    version match {
      case "v1" => v1(l)
      case "v2" => v2(l)
      case _ => 
    }
  }
}


val df = List("a-v1", "b-v1", "c-v2", "d-v2")
println(MyFilter("v1")(df))
println(MyFilter("v2")(df))
```

Now, If I have many versions, there will be a long list of  **case in match**. How can I avoid it and directly call **apply** method of **Object** using passed version which is string. It would be great, if someone can help.

Comment: What is wrong with a long match? Is simple and easy to maintain. What is good of reflection calling something with a string? is slow, unsafe, insecure, non-portable, and hard to maintain. - However, a good middle point would be using [**Enumeratum**](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) that way, you can use the `withNameOption` method to get the version object by a string.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Let say if I have hundred different versions then there will be a long list of case. Wouldn't it be hard to maintain? Thanks for the library. I will have a look.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed imagine having to maintain a piece of reflection code in production that someone kinda knows what it does but is hard to change, plus all the disadvantages that Luis said, it is much worse than a case with 100 lines that is quite easy to read.

Comment: If every v1,v2 etc filter does the same, why can't you just do `l.filter(_.contains(version))` (plus maybe checking if versions string is in allowed range - v1,v2 etc) ?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik no they dont. In reality, they are different and very long filtering conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a macro

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object MyFilter {    
  def apply(version: String): List[String] => List[String] = macro applyImpl

  def applyImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(version: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val q"${versionStr: String}" = version

    q"""(l: List[String]) => {
      println("Applying Filter")
      ${TermName(versionStr)}.apply(l)
    }"""
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
println(MyFilter("v1")(df))
println(MyFilter("v2")(df))

//scalac: ((l: List[String]) => {
//  println("Applying Filter");
//  v1.apply(l)
//})
//scalac: ((l: List[String]) => {
//  println("Applying Filter");
//  v2.apply(l)
//})
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of this. I will try that.